# Javascript/Webpack/React: using refs in a library is failing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a funny problem that I have reduced to the smallest use case I can. I have created a reproducible repo for this so you don't just have to take my word for it: https://github.com/bmeg/webpack-react-test

The idea is this. There are two separate projects in the repo, `app` and `lib`. In the library (`/lib`) I am creating a React component that I want to be usable by other projects. Works great from inside the library. Then, when I go to import that library into another project (here, `/app`) and it mostly works, except I get the "Only ReactOwner may have refs" warning detailed here: https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/refs-must-have-owner.html

Apparently it is common enough that they made a whole page for it.

From that page it tells me either I am creating refs outside of a render method (I checked, I'm not. Also, the refs work when run directly), OR: I am importing two versions of React.

How can I be importing two versions of React when only the library depends on it? Is webpack packaging up React in the library, then downloading and packaging it again in the app? How am I supposed to create a reusable library in that case?

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 0):

I just did a similar thing with my reusables. See [jms.react.components](https://github.com/jmarkstevens/jms-react-components). I did not use webpack, the build happens in the project using the library. From my package.json.

```js
  "scripts": {
    "dist": "eslint src && babel src --out-dir dist"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "latest",
    "radium": "latest",
    "react": "latest",
    "react-dom": "latest",
    "screenfull": "latest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "latest",
    "babel-core": "latest",
    "babel-eslint": "latest",
    "babel-loader": "latest",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "latest",
    "babel-preset-react": "latest",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "latest",
    "eslint": "latest",
    "eslint-loader": "latest",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "latest",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "latest",
    "webpack": "latest"
  }
```

It did not seem to work without eslint and since I happened to be using it anyway I kept it in the script. I borrowed the pattern from mx-react-components.

Comment: Hmm interesting. How do you call a component in the library from an application that is using it?

Comment: import {JButton} from 'jms-react-components';